# Protractor: Is it possible to use multiple .get() at the same time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, protractor, aurelia

I've probably phrased this quite badly, but I have a `<ul>` class and there are multiple `<li>` inside the element, I'd like to print the first five `<li>` entries but not sure how to go about it. I'm able to print off individual entries using `.get(1)` etc but I'm not sure how to use ``` .get(1)``.get(2)``.get(3) ``` together or if that is even possible.
This is how I approach it in my page object file

```js
checkFigures (figures) {
browser.sleep(8000);
   var checkBalance = element.all(by.css('ul.legend-numbers> li')).get(1);
 checkBalance.getText().then(function (text) {
      console.log(text);
     //prints 2nd <li> item
});
}
```

This is the HTML

```html
<ul class="deposit">
  <li>52,694.85</li>
        <li>21,779.65</li>
        <li>12,086.61</li>
        <li>358,314.56</li>
        <li>47,801.12</li>
        <!--anchor-->
</ul>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call .each() on an ElementArrayFinder. with filter() or map() you can get the elements you are looking for. [protractor element.ts](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/element.ts)

```
$('ul.deposit').$$('li') //get parent ul then all child li
            .filter((elements, index) => { //filter out the first 5 elements
                return index < 5
            })
            .each((element, index) => { //for each of the 5 elements do the following. (order is not guaranteed)
                return element.getText().then((text) => {
                    console.info(index + " - " + text)
                })
            });
```

Comment: Thanks a million that works, I had actually worked ahead using a uglier way that summed the first five elements but your method is much cleaner. My question would be, is how would I sum `text`. I'm using `console.log(index + " - " + text.toString().replace(/\D/g,''))` to print the elements in number format but would be ideal if I could print the sum of the five elements. I'm currently able to do this a different way but it's much messier than using filter() and map()

Comment: depending on if you need the index you can use [.map()](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/element.ts#L653) or . [reduce()](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/element.ts#L707) for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is the CSS Selector ":lt" (less than) that can be used with jQuery.

```
$("ul.deposit li:lt(5)").size(); //5
```

Can you use it?

```
$("ul.deposit li:lt(5)").each(
    function(i){ 
        console.info(i + " - " + $(this).text()); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm using Aurelia and it can be a bit awkward with Protractor, it doesn't recognise `ul.deposit li:lt(5)` I get a message stating an "invalid or illegal selector was specified"

Answer (score 0):

```
var combined = '';
function combineText(a){
  combined = ( combined.concat(' ') ).concat(a);
}
var checkBalance = element.all(by.css('ul.legend-numbers> li'));
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  combineText(checkBalance[i].getText());
}
browser.driver.sleep(0).then(function () {
  console.log(combined);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, when I run the above code I get,"don't make functions within a loop" warning

Comment: Really appreciate your time with this `a.getText().then(function (text) { ` results in the following error:  Failed: Cannot read property 'getText' of undefined
I've tried to see if I could solve the error but not sure what to do

Comment: What about now?

Comment: Hi, I get an error saying "Cannot read property 'getText' of undefined", I'm not sure what you pass into `getText()` as the function isn't called till after you use `getText`